# How can I avoid over-testing with example

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rspec, tdd

I've been trying to start testing my code more, and I thought I would mimic the style of some of the tests that were autogenerated for by me rails scaffolding (I'm using rspec and rails, but my question is really just general-tdd). However, those methods were very basic, along the lines of do something. then if foo, do something else. I feel like as soon as you get more complex by adding one more 2 more things to condition in your if, things start spiraling and you get nested examples all over the place. Here's an example of what i've been doing that feels like overkill.

First the method

```
def maybe_blah(foo)
  if foo != nil && foos.find_by_id(foo.id) != nil
    blah unless bar?(foo)
  end
end
```

this method is pretty simple, here's how I was planning on testing it

```
describe maybe_blah

  shared_examples "what happens when bad input is passed" do
    it "doesn't call bar?"...
    it "doesn't call blah"...
  end

  context "when foo is not nil"
    context "when foo is in foos"
      context "bar? returns true"
        it "doesn't call blah" do
           some code involving mocking bar? and blah 
        end
      end

      context "bar? returns false"
        it "does call blah" do
           some code involving mocking bar? and blah 
        end
      end
    end

    context "when foo is not in foos"
       include_examples "what happens when bad input is passed"
    end
  end

  context "when foo is nil"
     include_examples "what happens when bad input is passed"
  end
end
```

That's noticeably shorter than what the test would be if there was all of the setup and whatever else in there (testing maybe_blah for real like that took me 55 lines), so you can see how it seems to get out of hand. Is there a good way of testing a method that does feel like such overkill.

I don't see a way around having 3-deep nesting when you have 3 conditions you're testing (at least without repeating yourself even more), but it seems like you'd need to do that to make sure you're handling all different cases. Also, it seems dumb to test the fail result for every different bad input, but how else would you know you're actually failing on those bad inputs?

So is this just overkill?

Comment: I'm not sure what is considered best-practices there, but to me you shouldn't write tests that just repeat the implementation.  You write a test when it is easier to specify expected behavior with a test.  If it is easier to specify expected behavior with the implementation, then that is enough.

Comment: so you're saying don't even test maybe_blah?

Comment: Yes.  It is probably just because it is a made-up example, but there doesn't appear to be any contract that you could define for the function other than the implementation itself, and what you want to test is that a function satisfies its contract.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you condition is the same as:

```
def maybe_blah(foo)
  if foo != nil && foos.find_by_id(foo.id) != nil && !bar?(foo)
    blah
  end
end
```

Thus you can extract it into separate method using [Decompose Conditional](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/decomposeConditional.html) and [Consolidate Conditional Expression](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/consolidateConditionalExpression.html) techniques:

```
def maybe_blah(foo)
  blah if can_do_it?(foo)
end

def can_do_it?(foo)
  foo != nil && foos.find_by_id(foo.id) != nil && !bar?(foo)
end
```

After that you can test this method in two `contexts`

```
describe '#maybe_blah' do
  context 'when can do' do
    # stub can_do_it? and returns true
    # stould receive :blah
  end

  context 'when cant do' do
    # stub can_do_it? and returns false
    # should not receive :blah
  end
end
```

And test condition separately.

And you can omit `!= nil`

```
def can_do_it?(foo)
  foo && foos.find_by_id(foo.id) && !bar?(foo)
end
```

Comment: that seems impractical for larger operations though. If something had a bunch of steps, i wouldn't want to break it down into 20 different methods. it'd be messy and hard to maintain

Comment: This is a typical code smell because that complex condition is hard to read at quick glance. Otherwise you ain't be able to avoid deep nesting in your specs.

Comment: is it normal in practice to test all of those things though? I feel like most people arent' going to test for handling nil properly on every single method they write.